# Verifying if a given vector space is a Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

I was given a basis and a bracket denoting a bunch of relations on this basis of a Lie algebra. I am trying to prove that i have in fact been given a Lie algebra and thus that the bracket upholds the Jacobi identity.

The example i have is 7 dimensional thus i have a bunch of cases to check although i can eleminate a couple since i'm working with a nilpotent space. I was wondering if there is a 'smart' method to do this or if there are some sufficiant conditions, instead of going over every possible 3-tuple of basis elements.

Comment: We only need to check certain $3$-tuples, since the Jacobi identity is automatically satisfied if two basis vectors in a triple coincide. A $7$-dimensional example can be checked quickly - what are your brackets?

Comment: The brackets are given by \begin{align*}
[E_1, E_2] &= E_3,[E_1, E_3]= E_4,[E_1, E_4]= E_5,[E_1, E_5]= E_6,[E_1, E_6]= E_7,\\
[E_2, E_3] &= E_5,[E_2, E_4]= E_6,[E_3, E_4]= E_7,
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, this is a well-known filiform nilpotent Lie algebra. The Jacobi identity holds. It is $\mathfrak{g}_I(1)$, see my paper [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_18_deglie_7di.pdf), page $5$.

Comment: I believe to prove that the Jacobi identity holds we can exclude tuples of which the sum of the subscripts are $>7$, contain $E_7$ and such to reduce the amount of tuples, so yes, it probably isn't that much effort to check them all manually.

I was just wondering if there is a more efficient way for perhaps higher dimensional cases.

Comment: No, in general there is no shortcut. The polynomial equations in the structure constants arising from the Jacobi identity are difficult in general.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help!